# Getting callback from Yodlee Fast Link

Tags: callback, account, yodlee

Could you please tell me, how I can test integration with bank by Yodlee Fast Link without bank account(get success callback)? Is it possible?

Comment: use test credentials provided by bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dummy accounts which Yodlee provides.
To get dummy accounts you need to create a catalog for dummy accounts, which you can create [here](https://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/lndhaction.do).

For more guidance about the dummy accounts, you can visit this [link](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator).

Comment: thanks, @Apoorv. tell me please, at which point the response is sent to my callback route from yodlee fast link? automatically after step 3?

Comment: Once, the Fastlink will be closed, there will be a call to the callback mentioned by you. You can mention the callback in extraParams.